# Zipping files in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm zipping two files into one zipped folder in SSIS using the execute sql task. The expression I'm using is dynamic and evaluates to :

```
a "DestinationFolder.zip" "SourceFile_1.txt" "SourceFile_2.txt"
```

This works perfectly when both files `SourceFile_1.txt` and `SourceFile_2.txt`.
But sometimes there might be a situation where I receive only `SourceFile_1`. Then the task fails because of the missing `SourceFile_2`. How do I handle this?

Comment: You could create a dummy .txt file to be used when SourceFile_2 is null, but it would be better to compile a list of the files to be zipped that are actually present, then build your expression from there.

Comment: Improved layout and indented code.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the expression to handle this in such a way that, it should evaluate to "DestinationFolder.zip" "SourceFile_1.txt" in case sourcefile_2 is not there. You can use IIF clause to do this.